# On text change event firing in local but not in test server

Tags: asp.net

I have written code in ontextchange and made autopostback=true. When we give text in textbox and click on tab...on text change is firing and giving the alert. But when we give text in textbox and click directly on button, It is not giving any alert and directly saving with empty data...(We have written code to check duplicate values in ontextchange event).

Please help me on this..

Comment: where is your so problem code ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, It seems your `button click` event is taking precedence over your `onTextChange`

I suggest you to disable your button and enable it in `OnTextChange` event, So that both of your requests will not overlap.